# background-clip text breaks after using this property

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors, css-transitions

I am having issue with an background-clip:text it breaks after using relative for no reason I can see , text is there but there color is rendered transparent due to webkit fill color but it's not rendering the text gradient which was expected to be seen after position relative. after removing position relative it works perfect and I need to use it

this is my dummie code:-

So here is my code in `HTML`:

```html
<h3 class="colormanager">
    <span class="animation_control_js">
        <div class="internaltext">X</div>
        <div class="internaltext">X</div>
        <div class="internaltext">X</div>
        <div class="internaltext">X</div>
        <div class="internaltext">X</div>
        <div class="internaltext">X</div>
        <div class="internaltext">X</div>
        <div class="internaltext">X</div>
        <div class="internaltext">X</div>
        <div class="internaltext">X</div>
        <div class="internaltext">X</div>
    </span>
</h3>
```

For animation purposes I have to use `position: relative`, (working in FireFox but not in Google Chrome or Safari)

Here is the `CSS`:

```css
.internaltext{
    position: relative;
}

.colormanager {
    font-family:, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    white-space: none;
    margin-top: 15px;
    color:transparent;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #fff, rgb(231, 221, 221), #fff);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px
}
```

I tried the following:

- Using `inherit: all`

Using inherit in all

```css
color:transparent;
background: inherit;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

I didn't find any intresting answer so I here am I, asking questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use relative here.

Use it while animating with different classes and use *webkit* fill with idk shade of white or silver.

Eyes won't not the difference much and it will look cooler.

Comment: I see what u did there hehe, nice well I solve my own problems no one help .....